# MySQL Export exports Views first - and crashes immediately on Restore

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a production MySQL server that I need to dump a database out of.  The problem is that whenever I make this dump, it generates the View information first.  When I try to restore this backup, it errors immediately as the tables that back it don't exist yet.

Is there any quick fix to this issue?  I'm dumping the database via PHPMyAdmin.

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: Why can't you dump it with mysqldump?

Answer (score 1):

phpmyadmin generates incorrect backups (no table locks or REPEATABLE READ isolation level), so for serious backups you should really use mysqldump. It is also much, much faster.

Comment: While it may not be possible in every situation to use `mysqldump` instead of phpMyAdmin, I found that using it fixed the problem that I was having, which was the same as the one above. It creates empty tables for the views first, avoiding the problem of views referencing objects that haven't been created yet. Then after having created all tables and views, it then one-by-one replaces these empty tables with their proper view definition.